# Why does jquery .children() ignore the "td" tag?

Tags: jquery

Following code has unexpected behaviour:

```
console.log($("<div><div>Hallo</div></div>").children()[0]);
console.log($("<div><span>Hallo</span></div>").children()[0]);
console.log($("<div><td>Hallo</td></div>").children()[0]);
```

The first 2 lines work as expected. The third is undefined. Why is the "<td>" tag ignored?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yz2tbsc1/1/

Comment: Follow the rules, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_layouts.htm

Comment: The "td" tag is child of a <template> and will be copied to proper html inside a tr by js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser do some sanitization in bad HTML. The `td` tag inside a `div` is a bad HTML. It's expected to `td` be inside a `tr` or `th`.

So the browser removes the bad html tags, that's why you think it's ignoring the `td` tag.

Comment: Is there a way to stop that? It also happens inside a <template> tag (which is the usecase an error occurs)

Comment: "<div><td>Hallo</td></div> is not proper HTML, write proper HTML and it works, see previous link.

Comment: No way to prevent it. You must write valid HTML. Can you explain your use case?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed to <template>  using cloneNode and importNode, this works as expected. Dropped backward compatibility to preHTML5 though.